# nodemon --ignore not recognized

Tags: node.js, nodemon

According to the documentation, ignoring the Data.json file requires this command to be executed:

```
nodemon --ignore Data.json
```

[image]

I tried exactly that and it didn't work. The console kust returned:

```
Usage: nodemon [nodemon options] [scripts.js] [args]

See "nodemon --help" for more.
```

Other commands i tried:

```
nodemon --ignore 'Data.json'
nodemon --ignore "Data.json"
nodemon --ignore '/Data.json'
nodemon --ignore /Data.json
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass your `Server.js` to nodemon prior to the ignore

```
nodemon Server.js --ignore 'Data.json'
```

Alternatively you can create a `nodemon.json` file

```
{
  "verbose": true,
  "ignore": ["Data.json"]
}
```

and then pass this as a commandline argument

```
nodemon Server.js --config nodemon.json
```